# How can I assign a unique ID to all div's that have a specific class using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a unique ID to each div with the class of "owl-item". I would like the ID's to go in number order if possible starting with `<div id="slide-1"...` and so on. I can't seem to target the "owl-item" div's but only the div's inside of "owl-item" that have no ID or class assigned. How can I modify my javascript to achieve this? I cannot modify the html.

HTML

```
<div id="sample_slider" class="owl-carousel owl-pagination-true autohide-arrows owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
   <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
      <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 5456px; left: 0px; display: block;">

         <div class="owl-item" style="width: 682px;">
            <div style="padding:5% 5%; margin:0px 0%; min-height:100px; background-image:url(&quot;&quot;); background-position:left top; background-size:contain; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:rgb(248, 248, 248); ">
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="owl-item" style="width: 682px;"><div style="padding:5% 5%; margin:0px 0%; min-height:100px; background-image:url(&quot;&quot;); background-position:left top; background-size:contain; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:rgb(248, 248, 248); ">
            <div style="padding:5% 5%; margin:0px 0%; min-height:100px; background-image:url(&quot;&quot;); background-position:left top; background-size:contain; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:rgb(248, 248, 248); ">
            </div>
         </div>

         <div class="owl-item" style="width: 682px;"><div style="padding:5% 5%; margin:0px 0%; min-height:100px; background-image:url(&quot;&quot;); background-position:left top; background-size:contain; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:rgb(248, 248, 248); ">
            <div style="padding:5% 5%; margin:0px 0%; min-height:100px; background-image:url(&quot;&quot;); background-position:left top; background-size:contain; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:rgb(248, 248, 248); ">
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="owl-item" style="width: 682px;"><div style="padding:5% 5%; margin:0px 0%; min-height:100px; background-image:url(&quot;&quot;); background-position:left top; background-size:contain; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:rgb(248, 248, 248); ">
            <div style="padding:5% 5%; margin:0px 0%; min-height:100px; background-image:url(&quot;&quot;); background-position:left top; background-size:contain; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:rgb(248, 248, 248); ">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('#sample_slider div').each(function(eq, el) {
    el = $(el);
    if(typeof(el.attr('id')) === "undefined") {
        el.attr('id', 'div-' + eq);
    }
});
```

Comment: Element IDs should **always** be unique throughout the document.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to assign id's ?  It's possible that your end goal is better achieved another way.

Comment: @devlincarnate I provided a solution that adds a class rather than `ID`. I agree that assigning ID's is not the best idea.

Comment: I would like to set up anchor links to go to specific slides when clicked on

Comment: @Dambr7 : you probably can use DOM traversal to do this.  It also looks like you would benefit from using classes for CSS styling rather than all that inline style ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get all the div with class `owl-item` inside the container with id `sample_slider`.
Use jQuery each to cycle to all these elements and set as attribute the `slide-` prefix and the current `index + 1` if you want to start from 1, remove the +1 if you want to start from 0

```
$.each($('#sample_slider div.owl-item'), function(ind) {
   $(this).attr('id', 'slide-' + parseInt(ind + 1));
});
```

Comment: @Nice. I didn't know how to access the index of the `$.each` function. Thanks.

Comment: Had to wrap the code in `$(window).load(function()` Works now :) Thanks

Comment: Sorry I was having dinner. Yeah I was sure you were already coding there. Try to use $(document).ready(function() {}); . It should work too and it is better to use that event

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, although, you're using a wrong selector (`#sample_slider div`).

You need to target `.owl-item` instead.

So, you should do something like this:

```js
$('div.owl-item').each(function(eq, el) {
  el = $(el);
  if (typeof(el.attr('id')) === "undefined") {
    el.prop('id', 'div-' + eq);
    console.log(el.prop('id'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-item">

</div>
<div class="owl-item">

</div>
<div class="owl-item">

</div>
<div class="owl-item">

</div>
<div class="owl-item">

</div>
<div class="owl-item">

</div>
```

You should also use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you are asking. It finds all elements with the `owl-item` class and then adds the appropriate ID to that element. I might suggest using my second example - adding a class rather than ID.

```
//Iterate through each element with the class of 'owl-item'
$('.owl-item').each(function(eachCounter){

    //Add an ID to each element (slide-#) (eachCounter starts at 0, so add 1)
    $(this).attr("id", "slide-"+parseInt(eachCounter+1));
});
```

This example adds a class rather than an ID. I think this is a better solution.

```
//Iterate through each element with the class of 'owl-item'
$('.owl-item').each(function(eachCounter){

   //Add a class to each element (slide-#) (eachCounter starts at 0, so add 1)
   $(this).addClass("slide-"+parseInt(eachCounter+1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".owl-item").each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', "owl-item" + (i + 1));
    });
});
```

Should output unique ID selectors for you to use, such as:

```
#owl-item1,
#owl-item2,
#owl-item3 {
   color: $pink; // sample
}
```